# Python argparse choices from an infinite set

Tags: python, math, iteration, containers, argparse

I have the following code to create a container which pretends to behave like the set of all prime numbers (actually hides a memoised brute-force prime test)

```
import math

def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n == 1 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return all(n % i for i in xrange(3, int(1 + math.sqrt(n)), 2))


class Primes(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.memo = {}

    def __contains__(self, n):
        if n not in self.memo:
            self.memo[n] = is_prime(n)
        return self.memo[n]
```

That seems to be working so far:

```
>>> primes = Primes()
>>> 7 in primes
True
>>> 104729 in primes
True
>>> 100 in primes
False
>>> 100 not in primes
True
```

But it's not playing nicely with `argparse`:

```
>>> import argparse as ap
>>> parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('prime', type=int, choices=primes, metavar='p')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='prime', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'int'>, choices=<__main__.Primes object at 0x7f4e21783f10>, help=None, metavar='p')
>>> parser.parse_args(['7'])
Namespace(prime=7)
>>> parser.parse_args(['11'])
Namespace(prime=11)
>>> parser.parse_args(['12'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1688, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1720, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1929, in _parse_known_args
    stop_index = consume_positionals(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1885, in consume_positionals
    take_action(action, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1778, in take_action
    argument_values = self._get_values(action, argument_strings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2219, in _get_values
    self._check_value(action, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 2267, in _check_value
    tup = value, ', '.join(map(repr, action.choices))
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

The [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#choices) just say that

> Any object that supports the in operator can be passed as the choices
>   value, so dict objects, set objects, custom containers, etc. are all
>   supported.

Obviously I don't want to iterate the infinite "set" of primes.  So why the heck is `argparse` trying to `map` my primes?  Doesn't it just need `in` and `not in`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a documentation bug. This was [issue16468](https://bugs.python.org/issue16468), fixed in August 2019 by [PR 15566](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/15566/files).

The library as written requires the `choices` argument to be not just a container but also iterable,  It tries to list the available options, which isn't going to work for your case.  You could try to hack it by giving it a fake `__iter__` that just returns some informational string.

Comment: Thanks, I created an issue as you suggested [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue16697).

Answer (score 5):

The source where you're getting the exception is pretty clear, check it out:

```
if action.choices is not None and value not in action.choices:
    tup = value, ', '.join(map(repr, action.choices))
    msg = _('invalid choice: %r (choose from %s)') % tup
    raise ArgumentError(action, msg)
```

The check itself is fine. It borks on trying to print out a helpful error message, where it's trying to give you all the possible choices. I suppose if you define the iterator to return just something that has as its `repr` the string `primes`, you might hack it to do the rightish thing.

Answer (score 1):

`choices` are for arguments that you can enumerate all allowed values (a finite (small) set). The docs should be more clear about it.

`primes` is an infinite set. You could set `type` parameter to raise ValueError for non-primes.